# Acroread error regarding /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb

Tags: ubuntu, acrobat

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit).
When I do `sudo apt-get install acroread` followed by `apt-get -f install`
I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  acroread-bin:i386
Suggested packages:
  libldap2:i386 libgnome-speech7:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  acroread-bin:i386
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 374 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/60.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 142 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 501630 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking acroread-bin:i386 (from .../acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/mozilla/prefs.js', which is also in package adobereader-enu:i386 9.5.5
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running the following command in my Ubuntu terminal

`sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb`

after referring to [this link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/242406)